# How do update an attribute when any of the attributes of an entity changes in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

I have couple of entities that I want to sync with remote server. I want to mark the NSManagedObject instances dirty when any of it's attributes are changed. How can I achieve this without causing recursion. I tried doing this in validateForUpdate and NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification. But both cause recursion.